# Put an emoji in a Discord button with my bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do I include an emoji in a button sent from my Discord bot? I'm looking to include the `:arrow_up:` emoji. I know that I can include an emoji in an embed using `<:emojiname:emojiID>`, but this doesn't work. For example, this code:

```js
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("upvote")
            .setLabel("<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("SUCCESS"),
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("downvote")
            .setLabel("<:arrow_down:905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("DANGER")
    );
```

This results in buttons that simply include the string `<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>` text, like this:
[image]

I accidentally stumbled upon a method called `.setEmoji()`, but I've been trying different inputs and I can't seem to get it to work. It doesn't say that it's not a method, but rather I get an error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.components[0].components[0].emoji.id: Invalid emoji
```

I'm lead to believe that there's some way to do this, but I really can't find any information on it online at all. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Also, I forgot to include, but on Discord's own developer portal I found this: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#button-object-button-styles

It clearly shows an entry called "Emoji button", but it's not listed in the Button Styles list, so I don't know how to actually use it? But clearly it's there or it was at one point.

EDIT 2: This is my code when I use `.setEmoji()`

```js
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("upvote")
            .setEmoji("<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("SUCCESS"),
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("downvote")
            .setEmoji("<:arrow_down:905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("DANGER")
    );
```

This gives me this error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.components[0].components[0].emoji.id: Invalid emoji
data.components[0].components[1].emoji.id: Invalid emoji
```

Comment: In guide you linked they are using common emojis, and not custom server emojis

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft ?? `<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>` is not a custom emoji? What do you mean?

Comment: You are trying to add this emoji like if it's custom, use `⬆️` instead of `<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>`

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft I don't think what you're saying is correct... ⬆️ is a unicode emoji. I'm not asking about how to use a unicode emoji, I'm asking about how to use a Discord emoji... Since when is `:up_arrow:` "trying to add" anything? It's a default emoji in Discord........

Comment: If you try to send `\:up_arrow:` in discord - you will see it gives you `⬆️` which you need to use in code instead of `<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>`, to get this
```.setLabel("⬆️")```

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Yes, but that's not at all what my question is about. Thank you for the suggestion, but I already knew that and that's not what I want.

Comment: What's your code when you used `setEmoji()`? It should work when you replace `setLabel` with that.

Comment: @Taku I edited the question to include an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I see that should be valid. setEmoji should properly handle that input https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton?scrollTo=setEmoji, check if your emoji ID/name is correct and if the bot has permission to use them. It looks like your two emojis have the same ID in your example.

Comment: @Taku Oh, you're correct! I didn't realize that, but I had been right clicking the emoji and click Copy ID to get it's ID... But it appears I was mistakenly taking the _message_ ID instead of the emoji ID.... Which is very strange, because I did this before and it worked (I was able to get yellow and green circle emojis using the same method....) Well, how should I go about getting the IDs of the emojis? Clearly I've been doing it wrong, lol. I can't seem to find a way?

Comment: I know I'm a bit late but I wanted to ask if you solved this. Was the error that you used incorrect emoji IDs?

Comment: No, I was never able to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it works like this:

```
const row = new ActionRowBuilder<MessageActionRowComponentBuilder>().addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId(`customId`)
      .setLabel("SomeCustomEmote")
      .setEmoji("<:emoteName:emoteId>")
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
  );
```

working real-code example: https://prnt.sc/xQzPItncgrmi

P.S. I know this is an old post, but i hope this helps someone.

Comment: How is this different? OP uses `.setEmoji("<:arrow_up:905702018902011955>")` so it's the same as your`.setEmoji("<:emoteName:emoteId>")`, isn't it?

Comment: As far as I've been able to find emojis in Discord don't even _have_ IDs...

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros It's different, because i think he is trying to use default emoji, which you can use just with copy-pasting it (⬇️ let's say that's his arrow down), but all custom emojis have ID's, but they are little tricky to get.

To get custom emoji id:
1. From the BROWSER, go to the discord server you want and go to the emoji u want ( https://prnt.sc/Z5kRFsfXt9wl ) like in the screenshot
2. Inspect the emoji and you will get the id from here: https://prnt.sc/j6xGx7b2jakx
data-id is emoteId, and data-name is the emoteName
so in my case it will be <:happy:515265175058776075>

Answer (score 0):

In your code, add `.setEmoji('discord_emoji_Id_here')`. Then you put the discord emoji id in the space up there and that should work. Also try removing the emoji name from the script. LINK: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#emoji-buttons.

Example:

```
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("upvote")
            .setEmoji("905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("SUCCESS"),
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("downvote")
            .setEmoji("<905702018902011955>")
            .setStyle("DANGER")
    );
```

Try not putting the name of the emoji in the `()`.

Comment: Tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

ButtonBuilder#setEmoji does not ask for a string.

Example:

```
.setEmoji({ name: "" });
```

See if it works.

edit: if it's a custom emoji, put the id too

```
.setEmoji({ name: "hiowo", id: "19183801380" });
```